# Ошибка при ручном вызове события «OnDrawColumnCell»

Tags: delphi

Доброе время суток,
У меня есть несколько «*DBGrid*», которые должны окрашиваться одинаково и для придумал процедуру «*COLOR_GRID(const Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn; State: TGridDrawState; AGrid: TDBGrid);*» в которой выполняются действия по окраске всех «*DBGrid*». Данную процедуру я просто вызываю из собития «*DBGridDrawColumnCell*»

```
procedure TFRate.bvdbgrRateDrawColumnCell(Sender: TObject;
  const Rect: TRect; DataCol: Integer; Column: TColumn;
  State: TGridDrawState);
var
  Image_Sign_Deposit: TBitmap;
begin
  COLOR_GRID(Rect, DataCol, Column, State, bvdbgrRate);
  …
end;
```

- *все* отлично *работает*.

Но мне приходится, после редактирования таблицы, программно передергивать bvdbgrRateDrawColumnCell (для корректной окраски данных), способом

```
procedure TFRate.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Rect: TRect;
  DataCol: Integer;
  Column: TColumn;
  State: TGridDrawState;
  AGrid: TDBGrid;
begin
  bvdbgrRate.OnDrawColumnCell(Sender, Rect, DataCol, Column, State);
end;
```

но в этом случае при вызове «COLOR_GRID» **валится ошибка**:

> «class EAccessViolation with message 'Access violation at address
>   004041A4 in module 'MetaTrader.exe'. Read of address 00000036'.
>   Process stopped. Use Step or Run to continue.»

В файле «*…delphi7/source/rtl/sys/system.pas*», на строке

```
function _IsClass(Child: TObject; Parent: TClass): Boolean;
begin
  Result := (Child <> nil) and Child.InheritsFrom(Parent);
end;
```

Что я делаю не так?

Заранее спасибо за ответ.

P.S.
- Для упрощения, я закоментировал все в процедуре «COLOR_GRID» (ошибка осталась).
- Мне всетаки кажется, что я не правильно вызываю событие: 
Код:

```
bvdbgrRate.OnDrawColumnCell(bvdbgrRate, Rect, DataCol, Column, State);
```

Comment: Возникает AV, нажимаете Break, курсор становится на строку в system.pas. Вы не обращаете на него внимания, а ищете окно Callstack (если нет - идете в меню Вид-DebugWindows, и поднимаетесь по стеку до своего кода. Там вы увидите, в какой строке действительно возникла ошибка. Ставите на нее breakpoint (F5) и при следующем запуске анализируете состояние параметров, локальных переменных и т.п. Какая-то ссылка у вас равна nil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваш код:

```
procedure TFRate.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Rect: TRect;
  DataCol: Integer;
  Column: TColumn;
  State: TGridDrawState;
  AGrid: TDBGrid;
begin
  bvdbgrRate.OnDrawColumnCell(Sender, Rect, DataCol, Column, State);
end;
```

Ни одна из локальных переменных в этом коде не инициализирована, их значения содержат мусор из стека. Естественно, когда они используются внутри `bvdbgrRate.OnDrawColumnCell -> COLOR_GRID`, происходит ошибка. Хорошо еще, что это исключение.

Comment: Да, я уже понял **Igor**, вот при удачной проресовке, через "Watch" я заглянул в переменную "Column", ее значение равнялось *($22D3A8C, 0, $22A6E70, 'NAME', -16777211, 55, $4694DCC, $469BA18, imDontCare, '', nil, nil, 7, cbsAuto, taLeftJustify, False, [cvColor..cvWidth,cvAlignment..cvReadOnly,cvTitleCaption..cvTitleAlignment], True, False, True)*. Скажите можно ли как нибудь понять каким параметрам *Column* принадлежат данные значения?

Comment: @Konstantin78 Вы имеете в виду - "каким свойствам/полям". Можно. Вместо *Watch* используйте *Inspect*. Или в опциях *Watch* выберите *Structure* вместо *Default*.

Answer (score -1):

Все, решил.
- Мне что нужно было?...
- Просто перерисовать "Grid".
**Я про методы "Refresh" и "Repaint" совсем забыл**.